# How can I send a data to the client repeatedly?

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

I'm having an issue with the socket module when I want to send multiple files of differing sizes to the client.

I tried to solve this problem with a condition that is defined on the server (the size of file) and I sent it to the client with `s.recv(data_s)`.

When using this method, it works for the first file, but not the second. Here's the code I'm using to send the files:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question, but I think I have a code for this:

**SERVER:**

```
import os
import socket
import time
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('localhost', 80))

def send(path_to_file):
    byteamount = os.path.getsize(path_to_file)
    message = ("File Incoming:" + str(byteamount))
    conn.send(message.encode())
    time.sleep(3)
    FILE = open(path_to_file, 'r')
    FILEDATA = FILE.read()
    conn.send(FILEDATA.encode())
    FILE.close()

s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()

send(r'C:\Users\gener\Desktop\Programs\Counter.py')
```

**CLIENT:**

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost', 80))
while True:
    data = s.recv(1200)
    data = data.decode()
    if 'File Incoming' in data:
        data = data.replace('File Incoming:', '')
        incomingBytes = int(data)
        file = open('untitled.file', 'wb')
        data = s.recv(incomingBytes)
        file.write(data)
        file.close()
```